# Google Fonts: Cual es más rápido? rel="preconnect" o WebFontLoader?

Tags: javascript, css

Durante varios meses he estado usando el código Javascript de Google [WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) para cargar de forma asíncrona las fuentes de `Inter` y `Nunito` de Google Fonts:

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
      families: ["Inter:300,400,500,600,700", "Nunito:500"]
    }
  };
  
  (function (d) {
    var wf = d.createElement("script"),
      s = d.scripts[0];
    wf.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.28/webfontloader.js";
    wf.async = true;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(document);
```

Pero no tengo dudas de en cual es más rápida la carga. Será usando preconnect en el HTML? Gracias de antemano.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Nunito:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

**WebFontLoader** puede ser más efectivo para mejorar la velocidad de carga de las fuentes de Google Fonts en sitios web más grandes y complejos, donde se pueden requerir soluciones más avanzadas para manejar el proceso de carga de las fuentes. Sin embargo, en sitios web más simples, la atributo **rel="preconnect** puede ser suficiente para mejorar significativamente la velocidad de carga de las fuentes.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias!